# The meaning of Th(E) in default logic?

Tags: logic, notation

Hello I couldn't find an answer for that question anywhere. 
what is the meaning of Th() ?
and also the meaning of the more specific Th(E)=E
from Reiter's paper

Comment: In first order logic,given a language $\mathcal{L}$ and a $\mathcal{L}$-structure $M$, $Th(M)$ is the set of $\mathcal{L}$-sentences $\phi$ such that $M\models \phi$. I am not sure if this is useful for you. Could you include a link of "Reiter's" paper?

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psznza/G52HPA/articles/Reiter:80a.pdf
It was very helpful thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\operatorname{Th}(\cdot)$ is commonly used in logic for two different meanings:

- $\operatorname{Th}(\mathcal M)$, where $\mathcal M$ is a structure, is the *theory of* $\mathcal M$, defined as the set of all formulas (or sometimes only sentences) that are true in $\mathcal M$: $$ \operatorname{Th}(\mathcal M) = \{ \varphi \mid \mathcal M\Vdash \varphi \}$$
- $\operatorname{Th}(T)$, where $T$ is a set of formulas, is the set of *theorems* of the theory $T$: $$ \operatorname{Th}(T) = \{ \varphi \mid T\vdash \varphi \} $$

If the context is $\operatorname{Th}(E)=E$, only the second of these makes sense -- and in that case the equation $\operatorname{Th}(E)=E$ simply asserts that $E$ is a set of formulas that is closed under logical entailment.

Comment: Very helpful. thank you!